# PHP mysql stack bar charts using only column data

Tags: php, mysql, charts

I need to create a bar chart using **MySQL** and **PHP**. I have these fields:

- name of columns(string)
- PassTest1(int)
- FailTest1(int)
- PassTest2(int)
- FailTest2(int)

only by using one row , so my table is like this:

```
Name: PT1: PF1: PT2: PF2:
xxxx  75   25   54   46
```

in my bar chart i want to have this view:

```
x:axix number to 100
y:axix name of file
```

we will see 2 stacked bars:

```
PT1:PF1
PT2:PF2
```

How do I output the values in the bar chart this way?

Answer (score 0):

You could use php and build html and css for each request, but this seems like a really long winded way of working.

A better idea would be to use a js chart plugin like chart.js (http://www.chartjs.org/).

Then you can just pass either the echo'ed data or json from the php into the page and let chart.js handling for you.

Hope this helps.